# Part of a text link is not clickable

Tags: html, css

[image]

The link seems to have a "hole" in it. Do you know what could possibly cause this?

The link is structured like this:

```
<a href="[link to the topic]"><div class="post-title">[title]</div></a>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact HTML and CSS in the GIF?

Comment: some other element is interferring with it. This is easy , just use dev tools to inspect that element.

Comment: I just inspected it and found it was a silly error, I had a small image that had opacity 0 sitting on top with position relative that I forgot to delete, lol.